# Journey Builder - use API responses as pre-email/sms activity step checks within a Marketing Cloud journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketingcloudapi

We're looking to implement an APP acquisition campaign, where we send the customer an initial email, followed by reminder interactions depending on how they interacted with the initial email (downloaded the app but didn't register an account, didn't download the app etc). As well as a group that won't receive a follow-up. At present, I'm able to use our existing API to detect whether the customer has an API or not, however, we don't make use of the response until we send the email (driven by AMPscript logic within the email.

Ideally, we would enter customers' into a single journey and check their app status prior to each email/sms activity within that journey.

We were originally thinking something like (dates for illustration):

- Day 1: Send APP feature email to customers
- Day 7: Check APP status,
  if has app, send specific feature reminder, if doesn't have app, send
  APP download reminder
- Day 14: Send last chance email (there is an    incentive for our
  customers to download the app)

I'm wondering if there is a way I could use a decision split or other check within the journey prior to sending the follow-up comms so that I can track how many users end up down specific journey branches. Failing that, what would be another way to get the customers' app status before hitting the email activity within the journey.

Failing that, should I be looking to populate app status into another Data Extension and use decision splits based on values present in that DE (maybe populated from daily automation using the WM API call below).

We use the AMPscript variables above to personalise our content i.e. @hasMobileApp THEN show this

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Ben

````
Platform.Load("core","hidden");
try{
    // API endpoint, content type and headers
    var endpoint = "hidden";
    var contentType = 'application/json';

    // headers required for authentication
    var headerNames = ["hidden"];
    var headerValues = ["hidden"];
   var auth = "hidden";

    //Retrieve customer Number from Email AMPScript
    var customerNumber = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@customerNumber');
  var customerEmail = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@customerEmail');
  customerNumber = customerNumber ? customerNumber:0

    //Generate JSON payload for Request
    var payload = '{ "userName":"'+customerEmail+'", "customerNumber":'+customerNumber+'}';
  
    //Sends the request and receives a response
 
  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endpoint);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 1;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = "application/json"
  req.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", auth);
  req.method = "POST";
  req.postData = payload;
  var resp = req.send();
  var response = String(resp.content)

  
    //Parse content from response in to a JSON object to traverse through for variable values
  response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response)

    //Set variable values
     var status = response["Status"]
    var tokenizedURL = response["resestPasswordLink"]
    var lastLoggedIn = response["lastLoggedIn"]
    var hasRegisteredApp = response["isConfirmed"]
    var hasMobileApp = response["mobileDevice"]
    var hasActiveOnline = !lastLoggedIn ? false:true
    var failedCall = status!=500&status!=400&status!=409 ? false:true

  //return variables from API response to email ampscript
  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@tokenizedURL", tokenizedURL);
  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@hasActiveOnline", hasActiveOnline);
  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@hasRegisteredApp", hasRegisteredApp);
  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@hasMobileApp", hasMobileApp);
  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@failedCall", failedCall);

}catch(e){

  Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>```
````

Comment: I'm unsure of what the "Tokenized URL" is for, but is this a mobile app that has the SFMC Push SDK integrated into it? If so, you could just use your contact data in a decision split to see if they've downloaded and registered their ContactKey. See Contact Data -> MobilePush Data -> MobilePush Demographics when creating your decision split.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, Macca, we don't currently have the SFMC Push SDK integrated into the app (it's in the backlog). At present, we pre-register new customers and store a full URL in our WM DB, which I then retrieve and print in the email as the tokenized URL.

Comment: If an hour's latency in the download data is OK, you could put similar code to above in a loop, go around your Journey contacts and write to a Data Extension using an Automation. If you need realtime you could create a custom split activity. If your contact keys aren't too knowable and your tokenized url isn't that sensitive, you could host something like this on a combination of S3 and CloudPages (cheap). If it's sensitive, you'll need Heroku or similar($) for JWT authentication. A possible hack would be using exclusion scripting inside a dummy email in the Journey that never sends.